# Getting values in JSonArray

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I have a Facebook application in asp.net with C# and I get informations of "education" in a `JsonObject`.
The code is:

```
JsonObject basicData = (JsonObject)facebook.Get("me?fields=id,name,email,education");
string id = Convert.ToString(basicData["id"]);
string name = Convert.ToString(basicData["name"]);
string email = Convert.ToString(basicData["email"]);
```

And with this i transform the JsonObject into a JsonArray:

```
JsonArray educ = basicData["education"] as JsonArray;
```

OK. My Intent is to access the values ​​of the JSON structure, but I have no idea how to do that!
I tried to do the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < educ.Count; i++)
{
    Response.Write(educ[i].ToString());                  
}
```

That is the impression of each line:

```
{"school":
    {"id":"112933022109824",
     "name":"Colégio Estadual Antônio de Castro Alves"},
     "year":{"id":"138383069535219",
             "name":"2005"},
     "type":"High School"}
```

Comment: This question seems to have a good answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4748601/jsonobject-to-model-facebook-sdk

Comment: Hi, I will take a look. Tks a lot

Comment: Hi, yes I see this questions. Tks, helped me a lot.